# Is there any way to disable multi-finger tap event in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a gridview in Flutter which has multiple elements on a grid. Using multiple fingers, `onTap()` callback is triggered for multiple grid items simultaneously. Is there any way to disable multi-touch functionality? So far I have tried to create a custom tap recognizer class that goes something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

class SingleTouchTapGestureRecognizer extends TapGestureRecognizer {
  bool _pointerDown = false;

  @override
  void addPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
    if (!_pointerDown) {
      super.addPointer(event);
      _pointerDown = true;
    }
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {
    if (event is PointerUpEvent || event is PointerCancelEvent) {
      _pointerDown = false;
    }
    super.handleEvent(event);
  }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Using a boolean to track the state for the callback isn't fast enough.

Comment: Have you explored the concept of debounce? perhaps its a trick to eliminate this behaviour simply by delaying the function invocation?

Comment: I have. But debouncing didn't work in this scenario. Even if I am debouncing a function call, the multi-touch event is received much faster than the debouncer function can update its own variable.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a boolean `_pointerDown` to track the state, use a set to keep track of the active pointers:

```dart
class SingleTouchTapGestureRecognizer extends TapGestureRecognizer {
  final Set<int> _activePointers = <int>{};

  @override
  void addPointer(PointerDownEvent event) {
    if (_activePointers.isEmpty) {
      super.addPointer(event);
    }

    _activePointers.add(event.pointer);
  }

  @override
  void handleEvent(PointerEvent event) {
    if (event is PointerUpEvent || event is PointerCancelEvent) {
      _activePointers.remove(event.pointer);
    }

    if (_activePointers.length == 1) {
      super.handleEvent(event);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your grid you can use IgnorePointer for each element , then turn it off when one of the element is tapped like this:

```dart
class GridWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const GridWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<GridWidget> createState() => _GridWidgetState();
}

class _GridWidgetState extends State<GridWidget> {
  List<bool> ignoreList = [false, false];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GridView(
      gridDelegate:
          SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
      children: _generateChildren(),
    );
  }

  void _handleOnTap(int widgetIndex) {
    setState(() {
      for (var i = 0; i < ignoreList.length; i++) {
        // Turns true for selected widget and false for others.
        ignoreList[i] = i == widgetIndex;
      }
    });
  }

  List<Widget> _generateChildren() {
    final result = <Widget>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < ignoreList.length; i++) {
      result.add(
        IgnorePointer(
          ignoring: true,
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Placeholder(),
            onTap: () {
              _handleOnTap(i);
            },
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Maybe you can improve it by using some declarative functions approach, I did not test it performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this but still running into the same issue. By the time variable updates, all of the children have already received tap event. I am not talking about tapping one and tapping another. I am talking about tapping multiple at the same time in this scenario.